# Dispatch update to store no longer working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been doing react for a few months now and from one of the udemy courses I had a base template that used firebase.  I thought it would be a good exercise to try to update my base template to use firestore instead of firebase.  I thought this would be much simpler than it is - there are so many moving parts, and then even within the moving parts there are differences in versions.

The problem that I am having after having moved everything around a bit is that I can't seem to dispatch to update the store when the user logs in.  I suspect that this is an indication of a bigger problem.  I am going to try to include enough code so that someone may have an idea.

```
  //configureStore.js
  const initialState = window && window.__INITIAL_STATE__ // set initial state here

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  firebase.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })  

   const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(reduxThunk),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    ));

    export const auth = firebase.auth();
    export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

    const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  
  export { googleAuthProvider, firebase, store as default}
```

app.js:

```
  //app.js
const rrfConfig = {
  useFirestoreForProfile: true,
  userProfile: "users",
  attachAuthIsReady: true,
};

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rrfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance,
};

/* working firestore code
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
    <AppRouter />
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
*/

const jsx = (<Provider store={store}>
<ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
<AppRouter />
</ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
</Provider>)


let hasRendered = false;
const renderApp = () => {
  if (!hasRendered) {
    ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'));
    hasRendered = true;
  }
};


 ReactDOM.render(<LoadingPage />, document.getElementById('app'));
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {

   store.dispatch(login(user.uid));
    console.log ("store", store);
    console.log ("This prints out the UID correctly", user.uid);
    store.dispatch(startSetTweets()).then(() => {
      renderApp();
```

auth us file

```
  export const login = (uid) => ({
  type: 'LOGIN',
  uid
});
```

actions js file

```
export const startSetTweets = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const uid = getState().auth.uid;
      console.log("this returns undefined = ", uid);
```

I can see in my redux dev tool that auth is not correct

auth: {
authError: null
},

Answer (score 1):

in the reducer the switch statement was looking for the wrong action type.  Once I corrected this it was fine.

```
const authReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'LOGIN':
            return {
                uid: action.uid,
                ...state,
                authError: null
            };
```